# How do I get chrome's console to display a function with its dynamically changed name?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I do console.log on a function in chrome, it displays it using the function's original name, not the name at the time I called console.log.  For example:

```
var someFunction = function genericFunction() {}
Object.defineProperty(someFunction, 'name', {writable: true});
someFunction.name = 'specificFunction';
console.log(someFunction);
```

in chrome 43 returns

> function genericFunction()

which I find confusing.  I'd expect to see

> function specificFunction()

Where is it finding the old name of the function?  Is there some other property which I need to change to get chrome to accept the new name?

If something in the function throws an error, then chrome's stack trace does display the new function name.  This is what I'd expect, but seems inconsistent with the console.log behaviour.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you'll slap yourself ...

```
console.log(someFunction.name)
```

I hope you realise you wont be able to call the function using

```
genericFunction()
```

if you want to "alias" (for want of a better term) someFunction to genericFunction, simply

```
var genericFunction = someFunction;
```

Comment: Well, obviously that'll output the new name.  
It's just a bit cumbersome, particularly when later on I create objects using `var obj = new someFunction()` and assign properties to those objects.
Instead of `console.log(obj)`, I need `console.log(obj, obj.constructor.name)` and then remember to disregard the name in the first bit of output.
I'm not looking for a workaround, I just want to understand the logic behind the actual behaviour.

Comment: `Well, obviously that'll output the new name.` or the original name if new name hasn't been "assigned"

Comment: And I'm fine not being able to call genericFunction().  I only included that name to make debugging easier.